# Android Event Listener Data Binding for ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-databinding

Is it possible to bind a handler for setOnPageChangeListener to a ViewPager in XML file with the Android Binding functionality?

The demos show onClick events but I am curious as to how much event functionality I can implement with it. Any links on the capabilities of Data Binding would be great as well. Thanks.

Hypothetical example:

**example_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<data>
   <variable name="handlers" type="com.example.Handlers"/>
</data>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:onPageChangeListener="@{handlers.pageChanged}" />
</layout>
```

**Handler.java**

```
package com.example.viewmodels;

import android.view.View;

public class Handlers {
    public void pageChanged(View view){}
}
```

The compilation error is:

Error:(62) No resource identifier found for attribute 'onPageChangeListener' in package 'android'

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is possible to do this. You need to implement a custom binding adapter because there is no BindingAdapter classes predefined for View classes from Android support libraries.

For how to implement the custom adapter you may read [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#custom_setters).

The code should be something like the below, I haven't tested them thoroughly:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:onPageChangeListener="@{handlers}" />
```

Your BindingAapter code:

```
@BindingAdapter("onPageChangeListener")
public static void setOnPageChangeListener(ViewPager viewPager, ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener listener) {
    Log.i("setOnPageChangeListener");

    // clear listeners first avoid adding duplicate listener upon calling notify update related code
    viewPager.clearOnPageChangeListeners();
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(listener);
}
```

P.S. Your handler class being passed should implement `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`.

Comment: Not good solution. Because ViewPager adds OnPageChangeListener to internal ArrayList, calling notifyChange() for this property will make it to add several listeners.

Comment: @b1n0m updated to remove listeners first before adding listener

Comment: @David Cheung my listener is returning null when I debug the app. Any idea why it might be happening?

Comment: @DavidCheung if I have a `PageIndicator.setPager(viewpager)`. How can I bind `viewpager` to the `indicator`

Comment: @David Cheung, I also have a problem because when i add this code circle page indicator doesn't show current page. How to connect it with viewpager?

Answer (score 11):

Here is ultimate solution. Just put this class in your project.

```java
@BindingMethods({
    @BindingMethod(type = ViewPager.class, attribute = "android:offscreenPageLimit", method = "setOffscreenPageLimit"),
    @BindingMethod(type = ViewPager.class, attribute = "android:adapter", method = "setAdapter"),
    @BindingMethod(type = ViewPager.class, attribute = "android:currentPage", method = "setCurrentItem"),
})
public final class ViewPagerBindingAdapter {

    @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "android:currentPage", event = "android:currentPageAttrChanged")
    public static int getCurrentPage(@NonNull final ViewPager pager) {
        return pager.getCurrentItem();
    }

    @BindingAdapter(value = {"android:onPageScrolled", "android:onPageSelected", "android:onPageScrollStateChanged",
        "android:currentPageAttrChanged"}, requireAll = false)
    public static void onSetAdapter(@NonNull final ViewPager pager, final OnPageScrolled scrolled, final OnPageSelected selected,
        final OnPageScrollStateChanged scrollStateChanged, final InverseBindingListener currentPageAttrChanged) {

        final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener newValue;
        if (scrolled == null && selected == null && scrollStateChanged == null && currentPageAttrChanged == null) {
            newValue = null;
        } else {
            newValue = new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(final int position, final float positionOffset, final int positionOffsetPixels) {
                    if (scrolled != null) {
                        scrolled.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(final int position) {
                    if (selected != null) {
                        selected.onPageSelected(position);
                    }
                    if (currentPageAttrChanged != null) {
                        currentPageAttrChanged.onChange();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(final int state) {
                    if (scrollStateChanged != null) {
                        scrollStateChanged.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
                    }
                }
            };
        }
        final ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener oldValue = ListenerUtil.trackListener(pager, newValue, R.id.page_change_listener);
        if (oldValue != null) {
            pager.removeOnPageChangeListener(oldValue);
        }
        if (newValue != null) {
            pager.addOnPageChangeListener(newValue);
        }
    }

    public interface OnPageScrolled {
        void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels);
    }

    public interface OnPageSelected {
        void onPageSelected(int position);
    }

    public interface OnPageScrollStateChanged {
        void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state);
    }

    private ViewPagerBindingAdapter() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
}
```

Also add id resource in your resources.

```xml
<resources>
    <item name="page_change_listener" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

Then you will be able to use it in xml like:

```xml
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:currentPage="@={viewModel.currentPage}"
                android:offscreenPageLimit="@{viewModel.offscreenPageLimit}"
                android:onPageSelected="@{currentPage -> viewModel.pageSelected(currentPage)}"
                android:adapter="@{adapter}"/>
```

As you can see, `currentPage` has inverse binding, so your viewModel will be able to set current page and also get current page if user swipes.

Comment: are these setting able to update fragment in viewpager dynamically? in realtime?

Comment: @azizi-musa, you may set `viewModel.currentPage` value to select another page. If you want to change the fragments in `ViewPager`, you should do this in `PagerAdapter`.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `ListenerUtil.trackListener` stuff, along with adding and removing the listener?

Comment: @BigMcLargeHuge If someone calls `invalidateAll()` or `notifyChange()`, it would try to add another listener. So it is used to exclude situations when it can accidentally add several listeners.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `OnPageChangeListener`, you can use `SimpleOnPageChangeListener` and only override the method you're interested in:

```
@BindingAdapter("onPageChanged")
@JvmStatic
fun addPageChangedListener(viewPager: ViewPager, listener: OnPageChanged) {
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
            listener.onPageChanged(position)
        }
    })
}

interface OnPageChanged {
    fun onPageChanged(position: Int)
}
```

Layout:

```
<androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
    app:onPageChanged="@{viewModel::handlePageChanged}">
```

Handler:

```
fun handlePageChanged(position: Int) {
    println("Page changed: $position")
}
```

As others have pointed out, you may want to be careful not to attach duplicate listeners.