# How to convert ViewPager implementation using Data binding?

Tags: android, data-binding

MainActvity:

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static int currentPage = 0;
        private static int NUM_PAGES = 0;
        CirclePageIndicator indicator;
        int Imageitems[] = {R.drawable.hike, R.drawable.hike, R.drawable.hike};
        final ArrayList<Integer> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        ViewPager mPager;
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
            indicator = (CirclePageIndicator)
                    findViewById(R.id.indicator);
            for (int i = 0; i < Imageitems.length; i++) {
                imageItems.add(Imageitems[i]);
            }
            ImageSlider(imageItems);

        }

        private void ImageSlider(ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray) {


            mPager.setAdapter(new Item_SlidingImage_Adapter(this, ImagesArray));


            indicator.setViewPager(mPager);

            final float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;

            indicator.setRadius(5 * density);

            NUM_PAGES = ImagesArray.size();

            // Auto start of viewpager
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            final Runnable Update = new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    if (currentPage == NUM_PAGES) {
                        currentPage = 0;
                    }
                    mPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage++, true);
                }
            };
            Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
            swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(Update);
                }
            }, 3000, 3000);

            // Pager listener over indicator

            indicator.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    currentPage = position;

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int pos, float arg1, int arg2) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int pos) {

                }
            });


        }


    }
```

layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <data>


    </data>


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayout1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150dp"

            >

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:addOnPageChangeListener="@{data.pageChangeListener}"
                app:currentItem="@{data.currentPage}"
                app:adapter="@{image_adapter}"


                />

            <com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator
                android:id="@+id/indicator"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:padding="5dp"
                app:centered="true"
                app:fillColor="#ff0099"
                app:pageColor="#FF0000"
                app:radius="@{data.density}"
                app:snap="false" />

        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</layout>
```

adapter:

```
public class Item_SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private Context context;

    public Item_SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context, ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES) {
        this.context = context;
        this.IMAGES = IMAGES;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((View) object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return IMAGES.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, final int position) {
        View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.slidingimages_layout, view, false);

        assert imageLayout != null;
        final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
                .findViewById(R.id.image);

        imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES.get(position));

        view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

        return imageLayout;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view.equals(object);
    }

    @Override
    public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
    }


    @Override
    public Parcelable saveState() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

item.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="1dip" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Using given code I am able to auto flip in `ViewPager` and also using manually with some delay. I have to convert same code using `Databinding`; I tried but I am not able to understand how to set adapter,currentitem, and on page change listener how I will set value in xml?

How can I convert existing code for databinding in Android?

Comment: Right now you do not define any variable in your xml (and therefor dont bind any object instance to that variable). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44451536/2418367) for an excellent looking (but not tested by me) answer. That might be a very good starting point for you.

Comment: @Mhanaz Syed have you figured out how to do it? Because I'm stuck at the same place