# How to validate the value in EditText with the value of current item's position in ViewPager using the observer?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-livedata

I am using the ViewModel and Livedata. I tried getting the current position of ViewPager in ViewModel by using the following code

```
   <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/moveFromPlansViewPager"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:selectedItemPosition="@={ viewModel.selectedPos }"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:paddingEnd="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/moveFromHeaderTextView" />
```

Inside ViewModel I have

```
var selectedPos: MutableLiveData<Int> = MutableLiveData()
```

And I find the value in selected position and compare it with the value in EditText. Somehow I think this logic is correct. But the problem is while

```
 android:selectedItemPosition="@={ viewModel.selectedPos }"
```

When I add this line to the layout it causes databinding error.

> e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found databinding errors.

Can anybody help me???

Comment: What is the error message? You better give more explanation.

Comment: sembozdemir the error msg says 

e: [kapt] An exception occurred: android.databinding.tool.util.LoggedErrorException: Found data binding errors.

Answer (score 2):

Diving deeper into an error, it shows something like:

```
****/ data binding error ****msg:Cannot find the getter for attribute 'android:selectedItemPosition' with value type java.lang.Integer on android.support.v4.view.ViewPager ****\ data binding error ****
```

Practically it means that this particular attribute can't be binded **out of the box** (nor you can not use it like this `android:selectedItemPosition="2"`, f.ex.)

There're couple of alternatives

- You can add a [binding adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/BindingAdapter). F.ex. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44451536/1658267), there's a promising one
- Do it in old-school way: have an observer for the `MutableLiveData`'s `selectedPos` in the fragment and then just do the update there *manually*:

  ```
  viewModel.selectedPos.observe(this, Observer { position ->
          position?.let { moveToSavingsPlansViewPager.setCurrentItem(it, true) }
      })
  ```

First one is more advanced, the second one is easier to get up-and-running. So it's up to you.